# How to construct a group whose "size" grows between polynomially and exponentially.

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, free-groups

Define the "size" of a group with respect to an integer $n$ to be the number of possible reduced words that we can create by combining $n$ elements of the group.  For example:

1. an infinite cyclic group has size $\Theta(n)$
2. the free abelian group with $a>1$ generators has size $\Theta(n^a)$
3. the free group with $a>1$ generators has size $\Omega(a^n)$

I'm interested in the fact that free abelian groups grow polynomially in size, whereas free groups grow exponentially in size.  Is there a way to quotient the free group to get a growth rate between polynomial and exponential?

Also, is there a more standard term for what I'm calling the size of a group?

Comment: Try searching for "groups of intermediate growth"

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks!  I found lots of good references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of having an answer (CW): as Derek Holt says in the comments, what you call size is called the [growth rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Growth_rate_(group_theory)), and the groups you want are called groups of intermediate growth. Milnor asked in 1968 whether such groups existed, and Grigorchuk answered the question in 1984 by constructing the [Grigorchuk group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grigorchuk_group) and proving that it has intermediate growth.

See also [Gromov's theorem on groups of polynomial growth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gromov%27s_theorem_on_groups_of_polynomial_growth).